# Partial derivative with rightleftarrow on top of it

Tags: symbols

How can I write a partial derivative with an arrow on top of it (pointing to the left and right)? For instance:

[image]

I've tried to Google it, but couldn't find anything (probably because I'm not sure what keywords to use). Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

One option using `\overset`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}

\[
\partial_0\quad \overset{\leftrightarrow}{\partial_0}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ahhh perfect! Thank you. I will accept this answer (but for some reason I need to wait for 3 minutes before I can do that?).

Comment: @Hunter You're not allowed to accept an answer "too soon", so that more people can contribute before you "select". It quite makes sense, just the error/hint messages that come with it are not perfect ;)

Comment: @tohecz Thanks for the clarification; that does make sense.