# Looking for a command to create the geometry line symbol (\overline with arrows on both ends)

Tags: symbols, geometry

I need a way of encoding the geometry line symbol. `$\overline{AB}$` gives me the line segment symbol and `$\overrightarrow{AB}$` gives me the ray symbol, I need a way to get a bar over the letters that has arrows on both ends. `$\overrightleftarrow{AB}$` does not work.

Thanks!

Comment: You can use http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14/17423 with `\overset` to produce what you want.  Something like `\newcommand\Line[1]{\overset{\leftrightarrow}{#1}}`, perhaps (untested)  (By the way.... Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.(

Comment: take a look at [Partial derivative with rightleftarrow on top of it](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154793/579).  (if it is what you want, this question is a duplicate.)

Comment: Freakin' called it. :) Though, looking at the output, such lines are usually longer in geometry (at least with the professor I studied under).  There's definitely a question about lengthening that line, though I can't put my finger on it.  A combination of that link and the question I'm thinking of would cover this Q.

Comment: Almost found something that works: \newcommand{\Line[1]}{\xleftrightarrow[\displaystyle{#1}]{}}

The problem is that the line is justified with the text, not the letters. Both the suggestions with \overset don't make the line long enough.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use `$\overleftrightarrow{AB}$` with the `mathtools` or `amsmath` packages.

Comment: I think it looks much better with the MnSymbol package.  Of course, other symbols look less good with MnSymbol....

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
\overlinesegment{...}
```

from the the `MnSymbol` package.

Comment: Not the traditional line segment symbol

Comment: Thanks, this helped me.